# Why is my removeEventListener not working?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

My javascript code, thanks in advance (let me know if you need the html too but its basically the  tags, it's a game where the players just click until it reaches a certain number, and whoever reaches first wins. I'm trying to stop the other player from clicking if the game has already been won:

```
var player1Score=0;
var player2Score=0;

function p1Function(){

if(player1Score==document.querySelector("input").value)
   return;

++player1Score;
document.querySelector("#pOneScore").innerHTML=player1Score.toString();

if(player1Score==document.querySelector("input").value)
    document.querySelector("#pOneScore").style.color="green";
}

function p2Function(){

if(player2Score==document.querySelector("input").value)
{
    document.querySelector(".playerOne").removeEventListener("click",    
    p1Function);
    return;
}
player2Score++;
document.querySelector("#pTwoScore").innerHTML=player2Score.toString();

if(player2Score==document.querySelector("input").value)
    document.querySelector("#pTwoScore").style.color="green";
}

function resetFunction(){
    document.querySelector("input").value=5;
    document.querySelector("#pOneScore").style.color="black";
    document.querySelector("#pTwoScore").style.color="black";
    player1Score=0;
    player2Score=0;
    document.querySelector("#pOneScore").innerHTML=player1Score.toString();
    document.querySelector("#pTwoScore").innerHTML=player2Score.toString();
}


document.querySelector(".playerOne").addEventListener("click", p1Function);
document.querySelector(".playerTwo").addEventListener("click", p2Function);
document.querySelector(".reset").addEventListener("click", resetFunction);
```

Here is the HTML code as requested:

```
<body>
<strong><span id="pOneScore">0</span> to <span id="pTwoScore">0</span>
</strong>
<br>
<br>
<p>Playing To:</p> <span id="playing_to"></span>

<input type="text" name="score" value="5"></input>
<button class="playerOne">Player One</button>
<button class="playerTwo">Player Two</button>
<button class="reset">Reset</button>

<script src="scorekeeper_js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you show ur html also?

Comment: Why are `**` surrounding `.removeEventListener()` call?

Comment: Oh, I was just trying to make it bold, to show where it is...

Comment: Why are there two `if` statements having same condition `if(player2Score==document.querySelector("input").value)` within `p2Function` ?

Comment: Oh because one of them is to return if it reaches the limit, and the other is to turn it green. I tried doing it with one function but after it reaches the limit, I would have to click it again to turn it green, and I wanted it to turn green as soon as it reached the limit. Basically, I couldn't find another way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it now

```js
var player1Score=0;
var player2Score=0;

function p1Function(){

if(player1Score==parseInt(document.querySelector("input").value)){
   document.querySelector(".playerTwo").removeEventListener("click",    
    p2Function);
   return;
 }

++player1Score;
document.querySelector("#pOneScore").innerHTML=player1Score.toString();

if(player1Score==document.querySelector("input").value)
    document.querySelector("#pOneScore").style.color="green";
}

function p2Function(){

if(player2Score==parseInt(document.querySelector("input").value))
{
    document.querySelector(".playerOne").removeEventListener("click",    
    p1Function);
    return;
}
player2Score++;
document.querySelector("#pTwoScore").innerHTML=player2Score.toString();

if(player2Score==document.querySelector("input").value)
    document.querySelector("#pTwoScore").style.color="green";
}

function resetFunction(){
    document.querySelector("input").value=5;
    document.querySelector("#pOneScore").style.color="black";
    document.querySelector("#pTwoScore").style.color="black";
    player1Score=0;
    player2Score=0;
    document.querySelector(".playerOne").addEventListener("click", p1Function);
    document.querySelector(".playerTwo").addEventListener("click", p2Function);

    document.querySelector("#pOneScore").innerHTML=player1Score.toString();
    document.querySelector("#pTwoScore").innerHTML=player2Score.toString();
}


document.querySelector(".playerOne").addEventListener("click", p1Function);
document.querySelector(".playerTwo").addEventListener("click", p2Function);
document.querySelector(".reset").addEventListener("click", resetFunction);
```

```html
<body>
<strong><span id="pOneScore">0</span> to <span id="pTwoScore">0</span>
</strong>
<br>
<br>
<p>Playing To:</p> <span id="playing_to"></span>

<input type="text" name="score" value="5" />
<button class="playerOne">Player One</button>
<button class="playerTwo">Player Two</button>
<button class="reset">Reset</button>

<script src="scorekeeper_js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: No, see after the first player hits 5, the second player is still able to keep clicking...but the game is supposed to have ended so I don't want that person to be able to click.

Comment: Yes exactly! Can you explain to me why I need the parseInt, considering it was working without the parseInt before?

Comment: If you included parseInt, it will work even if the user typed any characters in it along with number like `5a`.

Comment: Okay, I guess my real question is, why did this work? What was I doing wrong before?

Comment: another two problems I found was that, You didn't give `removeEventListener` in one function and also you have to again add `addEventListener` in you RESET function

Comment: I think now you understand what is wrong with your code.

Comment: consider marking as answer and an upvote. @HyeShusho

Answer (score 1):

You didn't remove listener in one of your onclick functions.

```
function p1Function() {
  var maxScore = document.querySelector("input").value;

  player1Score++;

  if (player1Score == maxScore) {
    document.querySelector("#pOneScore").style.color = "green";
    document.querySelector(".playerTwo").removeEventListener("click",
      p2Function);
    document.querySelector("#pOneScore").innerHTML = player1Score.toString();
  } else if (player1Score < maxScore) {
    document.querySelector("#pOneScore").style.color = "black";
    document.querySelector("#pOneScore").innerHTML = player1Score.toString();
  }
}
function p2Function() {
  var maxScore = document.querySelector("input").value;

  player2Score++;
  if (player2Score == maxScore) {
    document.querySelector("#pTwoScore").style.color = "green";
    document.querySelector(".playerOne").removeEventListener("click",
      p1Function);
    document.querySelector("#pTwoScore").innerHTML = player2Score.toString();
  } else if (player2Score < maxScore) {
    document.querySelector("#pTwoScore").style.color = "black";
    document.querySelector("#pTwoScore").innerHTML = player2Score.toString();
  }
}
```

You also have to add listeners back in `reset()`:

```
function resetFunction() {
...
  document.querySelector(".playerOne").addEventListener("click", p1Function);
  document.querySelector(".playerTwo").addEventListener("click", p2Function);
}
```

Here is working jsfiddle code:
https://jsfiddle.net/1we2ydza/1/

Answer (score 0):

Once the 1st person clicks the 5, times then in the person one handler, the click handler for person two was not removed. Hence the person two was able to click. I think you hand missed to remove the click in 'p1Function()'. Adding the below lines in 'p1Function()' would solve your problem:

```
if(player1Score==document.querySelector("input").value)
{
    document.querySelector(".playerTwo").removeEventListener("click",    
    p2Function);
    return;
}
```

Comment: No, that wasn't the problem. I left that out because I was testing the first one. But either way it wasn't working. I'm still not sure why it wasn't working but the way the other two people wrote it, it works.

Comment: I used the code posted by you exactly. For me the logic was working fine for personTwo without any issue. For personOne adding above lines worked.

Comment: That's very strange....I had tried it so many times, and neither of them would work for me. Not even the one I had tried to remove the event listener of....

Comment: I have put up a plunkr with your initial code : http://plnkr.co/edit/uNAWdKXYG8AsKkrRFoaS?p=preview  Try checking this once. It works when personTwo click 5 and here after personOne clicks are not incrementing the counter